# Hashicorp vault: unable to write secret with node-vault

Tags: node.js, typescript, hashicorp-vault

I am writing an application which uses Hashicorp vault to store passwords and certificates. Right now I am using the default username/pass method to authenticate my client app.

When I try to add a secret I am getting `{ statusCode: 301, body: undefined }` when setting the `apiVersion = v1` and `{ statusCode: 404, body: { errors: [] } }` when it is set to `v2`.

Configuration:

```
let vaultOptions = {
    apiVersion: 'v2',
    endpoint: '0.0.0.0:8200'
};

const nodeVault = require('node-vault')(vaultOptions);
nodeVault.token = "secret token";

nodeVault.write('/secret/new', {"foo":"bar"}).then(
  function (value: any) {
    console.log(value);
  })
  .catch((err: any)=> {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

As the vault container is initialised by default I am not using the `init` function.

I would like to know what am I missing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue got fixed by adding `/data` to the path and also the request data had to be inside an object `{"data": .....}`.

```
nodeVault.write('/secret/data/new', {"data": {"foo":"bar"}}).then(
  function (value: any) {
    console.log(value);
  })
  .catch((err: any)=> {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

This was because the vault container was running on `v2 engine`

Comment: Hello, I'm facing exactly same problem but it still doesn't work even if I change according to what you did. What else could be? Thanks!

Comment: @EmilioNumazaki It's been a long time since I worked on this. Can you post the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Hi @Tony, in the end solution was exacly what you did but before I had to enable the path. Thank you!

Comment: Am I just being stupid or is the hashicorp docs out of date :/